# Is it bad practice to have executable code in my channel state object?

Tags: java, design-patterns, multithreading, state-machine

I have a `CommunicationStateMachine` object that's attached to my channels. It keeps track of who's turn it is to speak, how far along the conversation the server and client are, things like the client ID, all bytes read to date, the `ByteBuffer` etc.

My previous version of this server did some checks in the `Selector` thread (bad idea, I know), like checking if the message was complete, and checking if the client was a valid one.
To that end I had the methods that did those checks declared in the `CommunicationStateMachine.class` and the `Selector` thread called those methods on every `OP_READ` pass.

Now I'm removing all that work and putting the responsibility on the worker threads, and in order to keep things a bit cleaner I've decided to use the `State` design pattern. I've made a class called `Processor.class` which contains abstract methods. 
Depending on what mode the server is in (reading/writing text or reading/writing hex commands) I've created classes that extend `Processor.class` and implement it's methods. The result of the JSON mode processor so far is this:

```
public class JsonMode extends Processor {

    @Override
    public void processBytes(CommunicationStateMachine commsState,
            DataDAO database) {

        boolean validHeaderFormat = commsState.isValidClientHeaderFormat();

        if (validHeaderFormat) {

            boolean messageComplete = commsState.checkJsonMessageIntegraty();
            log.debug("JsonProcessor: messageComplete: " + messageComplete);
            String deviceId = commsState.getDeviceId();
            FirmwareFile file = database
                    .checkScheduledFirmwareUpgrade(deviceId);
            if (file != null) {
                commsState.setScheduledUpdate(true);
                log.debug("This is a scheduled update for " + deviceId
                        + " for file: " + file);
            } else {
                commsState.setScheduledUpdate(false);
                log.info("Device "
                        + deviceId
                        + ": Not scheduled for an update, scheduledUpgrade returned null");
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void prepareWriteBytes(CommunicationStateMachine commsState,
            DataDAO database) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

So my thinking here, is that the methods in the `commsState` object that are called here, such as `commsState.isValidClientHeaderFormat()` and `commsState.checkJsonMessageIntegraty()` should be removed from the `CommunicationStateMachine` object and placed in the `JSONMode.class` processor, meaning I will only call get and set methods from `commsState` and keep all processing outside that class.
This is the way to go right?  My thinking is otherwise I'll either start adding callable code for the other modes to the `CommunicationStateMachine.class` and it will get more unwieldy, or I'll have `JSONMode` code in the `CommunicationStateMachine.class` and other Modes codes outside, which would definitely be wrong.

Any other thoughts you might have on this process would be greatly appreciated too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that you should pull this functionality out of `CommunicationStateMachine`. Your state machine should only expose the methods necessarily to make changes in state and to query the current state. Your `CommunicationStateMachine` class should also be responsible for enforcing the rules of your state machine, i.e. ensuring that only valid state transitions happen. This logic is typically hidden inside the class and invoked when an attempt is made to change state.

In general, the approach you've suggested (the State design pattern) seems like a sensible choice based on your description of your requirements.

Minor note: you've got a small typo on `checkJsonMessageIntegraty`, which should be `Integrity` at the end. It may also be more intuitive if your class is called `JsonProcessor` to reflect its purpose.

Comment: Thanks!  I had just refactored JsonMode to JsonProcessor after I'd posted this question :-) I'll fix the typos, and thanks for your suggestion about enforcing state rules in the `CommunicationStateMachine`, It wouldn't have occurred to me to implement that.